# Issue with Overloading the Assignment Operator in C++

Tags: c++, overloading

I am trying to overload the assignment operator, and keep getting the error below:

```
StackLinked& operator=(const StackLinked& other);

template<typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType> StackLinked<DataType>::StackLinked& operator=(const StackLinked& other)
```

Error: warning C4346: 'StackLinked::{ctor}' : dependent name is not a type

Any idea how I can solve this? I am not able to edit the header portion, only the implementation.

Comment: Show enough of the class definition that we can see the first line is *inside* it, and that it is a template.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>& StackLinked<DataType>::operator=(const StackLinked& other)
```